# Trying to align all the content within my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web

I've been stuck with the problem of trying to align all the content (logos, links and facebook icon) on my navigation bar to all be vertically centered. I've done some research and a good topic from StackOverflow came up, which can be found here: [How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

I've tried the suggested ideas all to no avail. I'm really at a loss with this one and would appreciate any help in making my navigation look good across multiple browsers (mobile devices also).

Another issue I've come up with is being able to add content in the main body of the webpage. As you can see in the codepen below, some of the content written in the body is hidden by the header. I can add line breaks to fix this but I'm 90% sure the way I've laid out my content (header, main, footer all enclosed in body tags) is incorrect.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/ftahir192/pen/RRVkLQ)

Here is what I've done to try and fix the problem: `headerLeft` refers to the logo to the left of the links, and `headerRight` is vice versa. The header tag had a class of `verticalAlignHelper` but it seemed to do nothing so `verticalAlignHelper` isn't really being used now.

```
.headerLeft {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.headerRight {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


verticalAlignHelper {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated. This is my first website so I'd appreciate if the advice was as basic as can be. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

#### Prevent covered-up body content

Use JavaScript to set a `padding-top` on `body`, just larger than the top height. Like so:

```js
$("body").css("padding-top", $("nav").height() + 25);
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>Navbar</nav>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p>
```

#### Fix vertical alignment of nav-bar images

Because I can't see the images, the following are only suggestions:

1. **Easiest**: Make the navigational bar the same height as the image (or vice versa)
2. Manually hard-code margins in (only if you know exact heights of everything)
3. **Hardest but best** Use JavaScript (dynamic and fun)

```js
$(function() {
  var elem = $("#img4");
  elem.css("margin-top", (elem.parent().height()-elem.height())/2);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  height: 75px;
}
div.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.text {
  line-height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

img#img1 {
  height: 100px;
}

div#div2 {
  height: 75px;
}
div#text2 {
  line-height: 75px;
}

img#img3 {
  margin: 12.5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" />
  <div class="text">Uncentered image</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" id="img1" />
  <div class="text">Centered by making image full height</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar" id="div2">
  <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" />
  <div class="text" id="text2">Centered by making div same height as image</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" id="img3" />
  <div class="text">Centered using manual <code>margin</code> manipulation</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/square-xxl.png" id="img4" />
  <div class="text">Centered using JS and jQuery (dynamic)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still need to get into how to embed javascript into my HTML so I'll keep this in mind for when I learn that. As for the first part, for some reason, the links are okay, it's the images that aren't aligned (they touch the top of the window and the bottom of the navigation bar has significant space). This can't be seen because I didn't supply the images in codepen (nor do I know how to....)

Comment: @user3186023 For this post, you can stick all the JavaScript into a `<script>` tag and put that in your HTML after your code.

Comment: @user3186023 And for the images, you can host them online with imgur or something similar and change your img src to the online url

Comment: Ah, good point about the images. I'll do that to the facebook logo, however not for the company logo as I want the company to remain anonymous for now.

Comment: I have done as suggested with the image, and the codepen is updated in OP. Is there a CSS only solution for the fix you suggested for the main content?

Comment: @user3186023 If you know (approximate) height of the header, you can manually set the `padding-top` of `body`. The JS is just there to make it a little more dynamic.

Comment: @user3186023 In your case, I think a `padding-top` value of about 150-200px would be a good idea.

Comment: I added a padding top of 90px on main to fix the issue. Cheers. Any idea about the vertical alignment?

Comment: @user3186023 I'm glad the `padding-top` worked. Check out my answer about vertical-assignment (+ examples!)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I went with the first suggestion initially but because the logo and the facebook logo are different heights, the facebook logo is not center aligned. I may try hard coding using margin sizes for the facebook logo.

Comment: @user3186023 If they're different heights, the third solution is good for that.